# AMPScript to check content box in template

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I'm trying to get the ID (or any other credentials) of the content box into the template via AMP script. This is to apply styling for the table wrapping the area if there is no content.

Can you please advise if that is possible?

Here is the example of the code:

```
<tr>
  <td><table width="580" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="The_Class_I_am_trying_to_apply">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height: 14px;"><custom type="content" name="Content 3"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to conditionally hide/show template content placeholders.

My recommendation would be to script the entire block and not rely on the template. Just store what you would typically put in the placeholder in a named content area:

```
%%[
/* init script block */
var @content1
set @content1 = ContentAreaByName("my contents\content1")

]%%

<!-- other HTML -->

%%[ if not empty(@content1) then ]%%

<!-- content here --> 

%%[ endif ]%%
```